# Dropwizard Auth2.0 Client implementation

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, client, dropwizard

i read on this page https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/auth.html that is possibile write a service based on Auth2.0, but i can't understand how can i do this thing.
Someone can help me?

Comment: Only base auth. i want to follow some example but i don't find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a cause, why there are no oauth2 examples. With Oauh2 you have one problem. The way from client to oauth2 server is well defined, but the validation between service and oauth2service can be very custom. Thats why I have written my own Oauth2 Bundle and Oauth2 Service provider for that. So thats why my description below is just theory!

With the link provided by you, it should be easy to implement Oauth2 protected ressources, if you validate the Token yourself.

> ```
>    environment.jersey().register(AuthFactory.binder(new OAuthFactory<User>(new ExampleAuthenticator(),
>                                                                            "SUPER SECRET STUFF",
>                                                                            User.class)));
> ```

Then use this annotation

> ```
> @GET
> public SecretPlan getSecretPlan(@Auth User user) {
>     return dao.findPlanForUser(user);
> }
> ```

Now you have to implement your Oauth2 authenticator and thats the tricky part, because you have to know your validation server/service. Most of them are different. In most cases you have to take the provided String-Token and then you can verify if the user is registered at the Oauth2 Validation provider.

A short Oauth2 Overview:

1. Client request a token from Oauth2 service provider (FB, Google,...)
2. Client send token to your DW app as hhtp Auth header
3. Your DW app can validate the token against your prefered oauth2 service provider
4. Oauth2 servide provider checks if the token was released by itself and tells your DW app if token is valid or not and in most cases (like FB) you can get access to the client profile or whatever.

I validate the token against my own Oauth2 service, so this is why my authenticator is very custom and does not help you.

If you want to validate your oauth2 token against, e.g. Facebook, then please read some facebook oauth2 [tutorials](http://facebook4j.org/en/code-examples.html) or any other tutorial or even one for other Oauth2 Validation service providers like Google, Amazon, Instagram ...

If Oauth2 is now to much work for you, why dont you use HTTP basic Auth? In most cases this is all you need for a little DW application.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/na703/DropwizardRethinkDB) is an example of using Dropwizard Oauth2 with a custom authentication mechanism.